# Como instalar o composer no Mac manualmente

Tags: php, composer

Estou com dificuldade para instalar o composer no mac pelo terminal, existe alguma maneira de instalar sem utilizar o terminal? Eu já havia instalado antes mas agora por algum motivo que desconheco sumiu e nao estou conseguindo instalar, sempre que uso o terminal fica **dando-bash: composer: command not found**

minha versao do PHP é 7.0.4 se nao me engano.
Mac sierra versao 10.12.
Utilizo o VSCODE

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122764/discussion-on-question-by-augustus-nascimento-como-instalar-o-composer-no-mac-ma)